# Issue while opening Spark shell

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to open spark using command

> $ spark-shell

but getting warning. How to fix it.

**Warning:**

```
WARN util.Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
```

Comment: Are those ports free? Can you check it please? Do you have other Spark processes in the background? Please also provide configuration code

Comment: No they are not free. how can i make them free ?

Comment: Temporary option: kill processes. But to investigate what's going on, we must see your code, maybe there is some problem

Comment: how can i kill the process ?

Comment: On linux `kill pid` command, on Windows you must to open Task Manager. But it's only a workaround for now, if code is not correct it can not help you

Comment: @T.Gawęda code is correct. i face this issue when i close the terminal when i am in shell and try to open spark shell again after opening terminal.

Comment: Sorry, I had to ask you to be sure :) Because you may have already Standalone server or some streaming job in the background. When exiting Spark-shell, please do Ctrl+D, it will close shell in proper way. Do restart and try in this way :)

Comment: @T.Gawęda Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, Spark will try to bind port 4040.
 In your case there is already a spark process running on 4040.

The following message isn not an error as spark will run on port 4041:

```
WARN util.Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
```

From [Spark Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html):

> Every SparkContext launches a web UI, by default on port 4040, that
>   displays useful information about the application. This includes:
>
> If multiple SparkContexts are running on the same host, they will bind to successive ports
>   beginning with 4040 (4041, 4042, etc).

Comment: yes i understood it. I also updated my comments. But what is the solution when both the ports are busy. In my case the shell gets stuck as both ports are busy.

Comment: @animal What is spark.master or deploy mode? Yarn/standalone cluster?

Answer (score 10):

Spark port you can change anytime when running in the command prompt

[hadoop@localhost ~]$ spark-shell --conf spark.ui.port=4041

by default, spark run into the 4040

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer also helped me to start a spark sheet. On further research, I found that there is 16 attempt given by spark to auto-allocate a port. 
[Refer to Spark Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

[image]

A good thing is that spark also suggests how to configure a new unused port and start the spark shell the port

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Service 'SparkUI' failed after 16 retries (starting from 4040)! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate port for the service 'SparkUI' (**for example spark.ui.port for SparkUI**) to an available port or increasing spark.port.maxRetries.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why:** When a spark-shell is open, it checks port 4040 for availability. If this port is already in use then it checks the next one "4041", and so on.

**Solution:** Initiate spark-shell command using below option. Try different UI ports (Instead of 64080, you can try any random non-CDH port numbers)

```
$ spark-shell --conf spark.ui.port=14058

$ set spark.port.maxRetries=30
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the pid of the process running on port 4040:

```
ss -lptn 'sport = :4040'
```

To terminate it:

```
kill -9
```